# iOS: How to trigger a refresh of constraints/autolayout of a tableViewCell when its accessoryView changes?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel, constraints

I have got a custom tableview + custom cells that are constructed using constraint-based autolayout (all programmatically, no IB). In each cell there is (amongst others) a (potentially) multiline Label with text. The first calculation of autolayout is fine - i.e. the UILabel wraps correctly according to its textlength.

But I have a layout issue once I select a cell (i.e. change from UITableViewCellAccessoryNone to UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) AND the number of needed lines for the UILabel.text should change - but instead remains the same.

I tried...

```
[myTableView reloadData];
```

and

```
[myTableView beginUpdate];
[myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[myTableView endUpdates];
```

...in the delegate for cell-selection but had no success for updating the layout of the cell.

I suppose that I need to tell the system to reevaluate the constraints of the tableviewcell (specifically to reevaluate to preferredMaxLayoutWidth for the UILabel.) But I have no idea on how to do that the correct way. 
(I tried a few things with setNeedsUpdate but rather trial-and-error-style.)

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: For multiline labels you have to provide Preferred Max Layout Width on constraint update   - (void)updatePreferredMaxLayoutWidth:(UILabel *)label
{
    label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth =
        [label alignmentRectForFrame:label.frame].size.width;
}

Answer (score 1):

You have to specifically  reevaluate to preferredMaxLayoutWidth for the UILabel by the following way:-

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self updatePreferredMaxLayoutWidth:self.lblText]; // you have to store a UIlabel temporarily on didselectaction of UITableView
    [self.view layoutSubviews];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out here! Just to make sure - do I need to subclass UILabel for this or does the above code belong somewhere else (viewcontroller, tableview, cell)? (BTW. I set myLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth currently within the updateConstraints method of my custom cell just before calling [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded] and [super updateConstraints]...)

Comment: yeah mate you can set myLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth in between[self.view layoutSubviews] and  [super viewDidLayoutSubviews]  , the method  (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews you have to provide in your Custom UITableViewCell class if you are using custom class, otherwise for prototype Cell, you can put the down in your ViewController class, but you have to get the Selected Cell's UILabel  from your tableview.